# Setting WooCommerce currency programmatically

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have an issue where I need to change the currency programmatically. I am doing an AJAX call and I have noticed that returned results does not take into account which currency the user has set.

So I am now assigning the currency on the $.ajax call, however, the issue is getting WordPress to change the currency programmatically on this call. I am very surprised to see that there's not aparent answer to this.

I would expect a function like `woocommerce_set_currency('EUR')`.

So basically I need to change viewed currency for a template like so:

```
set_viewed_currency('USD'); // some function to change currency before rendering
wc_get_template('modal-single-product.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspecting of the source code of the plugin we're using (WooCommerce Multicurrency) I found this solution:

```
WOOMULTI_CURRENCY_Data::get_ins()->set_current_currency($_POST['wmc-currency']);
```

However, I would love if there was a more straightforward native way using woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the page id that you will change the currency on it, then return the new currency to woocommerce filter `woocmmerce_currency`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency', 'change_woocommerce_currency' );
function change_woocommerce_currency( $currency ) {
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        return false;
    }
    global $post;
    $current_page_id = $post->ID;
    $saved_page_id   = 15; //get the page id you want
    if ( $current_page_id == $saved_page_id ) {
        $currency = '$$$'; // or whatever the currency symbol is
    }

    return $currency;
}
```